# C++ use of explicit suggested by cppcheck

Tags: c++, explicit, cppcheck, explicit-constructor

Is using the cast constructor bad?
Otherweise why a code quality checker (cppcheck in my case) would constantly suggest to add explicit before single parameter constructors?

What if I want to do

```
class MyClass {  
 A(int) {}
};

A a = 1;
```

If I follow the "suggestions" and write

```
class MyClass {  
 explicit A(int) {}
};

A a = 1;
```

would throw an error, but if I use the first I'll have a warning that i've to document to pass the code reviews.

Comment: Checkers like cppcheck check against *style* guidelines.   Some style guidelines  discourage use of single-argument "cast" constructors, and encourage making them explicit, because doing so avoids unintended implicit conversions.    The point of such style guidelines is *requiring* you to document an explicit justification for implicit casting constructors whenever you use them.

Comment: The direct solution is to initialize with `A a{1};`

Comment: You might disable the check locally, see for example [cppcheck-inline-suppression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701104/cppcheck-inline-suppression-not-working).

Comment: See also: [Should I really massively introduce the explicit keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052326/should-i-really-massively-introduce-the-explicit-keyword)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such implicit class type conversion can be used easily without intention. With this converting constructor every function or member function which accepts `MyClass` as argument will accept also `int`. Therefore every `int` passed to such a function will be converted to a temporary `MyClass` which will be discarded after the function has finished. Probably not what you want.

Answer (score 6):

[C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md)

> [C.46](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-explicit): By default, declare single-argument constructors explicit
>
> **Reason**
>
> To avoid unintended conversions.
>
> **Example, bad**
>
> ```
> class String {
> public:
>     String(int);   // BAD
>     // ...
> };
>
> String s = 10;   // surprise: string of size 10
> ```
>
> **Exception**
>
> If you really want an implicit conversion from the constructor
> argument type to the class type, don't use explicit:
>
> ```
> class Complex {
> public:
>     Complex(double d);   // OK: we want a conversion from d to {d, 0}
>     // ...
> };
>
> Complex z = 10.7;   // unsurprising conversion
> ```
>
> See also: [Discussion of implicit conversions](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ro-conversion)